# setup VXLAN forwarding to multiple destination on Linux

Tags: linux, bridge, vxlan

I can't setup forwarding of all zero (unknown, I assume)/multicast ethernet frames to multiple unicast IPs (virtual tunnel endpoints), although it seems that it should be supported (also mentioned [here on page 8](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/2013-linuxcon.pdf)) in kernel since version 3.8.0 when the Dove extension was merged into mainline.

```
# bridge fdb add 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev vxlandev dst 10.0.1.1
# bridge fdb add 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev vxlandev dst 10.0.1.2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

I need to use original Linux bridge, not Openvswitch or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer myself - unlike with ip command, you have to use `append` keyword, not `add`

therefore it should be:

```
# bridge fdb add 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev vxlandev dst 10.0.1.1
# bridge fdb append 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev vxlandev dst 10.0.1.2
```